# removeMouseListener not removing the listener added in another function, despite everything else retaining values

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

```
static MouseAdapter[][] clickCase = new MouseAdapter[8][8];

    public static void highlight(int[] x, int[] y, Piece piece) {
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0x94dccb), 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            chessCase[x[i]][y[i]].setBorder(border);
            chessCase[x[i]][y[i]].repaint();
            int finalI = i;

            setClickCase(x[i], y[i], piece);
            chessCase[x[i]][y[i]].addMouseListener(getClickCase(x[i], y[i]));
        }
    }

    public static void unHighlightAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                chessCase[i][j].setBorder(null);
                chessCase[i][j].removeMouseListener(clickCase[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void setClickCase(int x, int y, Piece piece) {
        clickCase[x][y] = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                Board.setPiece(piece, x, y);
                unHighlightAll();
            }
        };
    }

    private static MouseAdapter getClickCase(int x, int y) {
        return clickCase[x][y];
    }
```

Hey, I'm trying to make a game of chess. And for some reason, inside the unHighlightAll method (Which just unhighlights the whole board and removes the ability to put a chess piece anywhere on the board), the line :
 `chessCase[i][j].removeMouseListener(clickCase[i][j]);` isn't doing it's job. I can still click on those cases despite the highlight being removed, meaning it's that one line in particular that's causing problem. So the code is indeed accessing this block.

I suspected it might be something like the values are not being retained from a function to another, but I've tried with various data types, such as integers, and the value is the same as it should be.

I've tried to write a reprex, but I can't for the life of me, it just ends up being more buggy with like maybe 50 less lines, which were just lines that had to do with the design of the board. So I'll link to my github instead which contains the last "stable" version of the project with the current bug : https://github.com/KevinSlim67/Chess

Comment: You should probably remove the previous 'MouseListener' in 'setClickCase'

Comment: This resolved the problem ! Thank you ^^ Just had to add :
chessCase[x][y].removeMouseListener(getClickCase(x,y)); 
before the declaration of the clickCase !